# Как добавить нужное приложение в быстрый доступ

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте я не очень понимаю как мне правильно задать это вопрос но всё же. Мне нужно что бы я имел доступ к файлу по определенной команде в терминал например как я пишу cat, gedit, nano, firefox. Могу ли я как-то сделать так-же со своим приложение по нужному пути что-бы не прописывать всегда длинный путь например вместо(./home/user/app/file.sh) я мог написать в терминале file и он выполнял весь путь?

Comment: В bin его прописать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решаю задачу через **алиасы**, которые добавляются в файл *~/.bashrc* .

Например, добавление строки

```
alias nn='sudo nano /etc/hosts'
```

приведет к тому, что при вызове `nn` в терминале через судо откроется файл hosts .

После внесения изменений, `bashrc` нужно обновить командой:

```
source .bashrc
```